# With the spell blink, could you deposit an object on the Ethereal plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ethereal-plane

Let's say you ready an action, that when you are on the ethereal plane you will drop your weapon. Does this work, would you return to the material plane without a weapon? Could you blink again and pick it back up later?

> [Blink](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blink): ...you vanish from your current plane
>   of existence and appear in the Etheral Plane...
>   At the start of you next turn, and when the spell ends if you are on
>   the Etheral Plane, you return to an unoccupied space of your choice
>   that you can see within 10 feet of the space you vanished from.

A scenario where this could be very useful, imagine you are holding a ticking time bomb, you blink into the ethereal plane drop the bomb and blink back just in time, saving your party from the explosion.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143294/if-i-am-holding-an-item-before-i-cast-blink-will-it-move-with-me-through-the-et

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It would be reasonable to assume that is possible

You can ready an action to interact with an object. There are no restrictions on interacting with objects while blinking. There is no text saying that objects you are carrying while blinking must be brought back to the original plane.

Even though this is a valid way to use the rules, there is nothing explicitly saying it is possible. While personally I think this is an interesting and inventive use of the game mechanics, and it does not violate any rules, ultimately it is up to the DM.